# How to get User Image from class "User" in UIImageView? Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, uiimageview, parse-platform

I want to download the image in a UIImageView user from Parse. In the User section, I created the UserImage section, but I can not download it into UIImageView, what should I do? You give me a hand? Help me please.

I've used this code:

```
PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {

    PFQuery* queryPhoto = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserImage"];

    [queryPhoto findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        // Verify if there are no errors
        if (!error) {

            // Retrieve Usename
            User.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]valueForKey:@"username"]] ;

            // Retrieve Photo

            PFUser *currentuser = [PFUser currentUser];
            PFFile *file = [currentuser objectForKey:@"UserImage"];

            [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    // image can now be set on a UIImageView

                    self.UserImages.image = image;
                }
            }];
        }

        else {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlertView show];

        }

    } ];

}
```

Comment: Did you get any error or get no image? also check for class name and file column name in user class.

Comment: No no error in particular, the image is recognized correctly but will not load nell'UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com has the PFImageView specifically to make this task eaiser.

Try this:

```
PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    PFQuery* queryPhoto = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserImage"];

    [queryPhoto findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        // Verify if there are no errors
        if (!error) {

            // Retrieve Usename
            User.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]valueForKey:@"username"]] ;

            // Retrieve Photo & Load
            PFFile *file = [currentUser objectForKey:@"UserImage"];
            PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init]; 
            self.UserImages.image = imageView; //Assuming here that you set self.UserImages.image as a PFImageView
            self.UserImages.image.file = file; 
            [self.UserImages.image loadInBackground]; 
       }

        else {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlertView show];

        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: "self.UserImages.image.file = file" tells me that the string is not correct

Comment: How are you setting [currentUser objectForKey:@"UserImage"] ? Is that a valid PFFile?